# Contagem Distinta por data

Tags: python

Tenho uma lista de clientes por data e precisava contar quantos clientes distintos tenho em cada dia, por exemplo:

```
Date             Cod_Cli
10/01/2023       A
10/01/2023       A
10/01/2023       A
10/01/2023       A
10/01/2023       B
10/01/2023       B
11/01/2023       A
11/01/2023       B
```

A resposta que preciso é dia 10/01/2023 2 clientes e dia 11/01/2023 também 2 clientes.

Tentei de duas formas e não deu certo.

Tentativa 1:

```
lista_aux = []
lista_data = []
for h in his_corretagem_bovespa:
  lista_aux.append(h['Cod_Cli'])
  lista_aux.append(h['Date'])
  lista_data.append(h['Date'])
  
lista_aux = list(dict.fromkeys(lista_aux))
lista_data = list(dict.fromkeys(lista_data))

lista_contagem = []
for l in lista_data:
  qtd_cliente = 0
  l['Date'] = int(l['Date'])
  for m in lista_aux:
    m['Date'] = int(m['Date'])
    if l['Date'] == m['Date']:
      qtd_cliente = qtd_cliente + 1
    
    lista_contagem.append({'Data':['Date'], 'Qtd_Cliente': qtd_cliente})
```

Tentativa 2:

```
teste = []
clientes = []
for h in his_corretagem_bovespa:
  teste.append({'Data':h['Date'], 'Cliente':h['Cod_Cli'],'Chave':str(h['Cod_Cli'])+h['Date']})
  
df_teste = pd.DataFrame(teste)

df_teste = df_teste.groupby(['Chave','Data','Cliente'])

conta = (df_teste.count('Chave'))

print(conta)
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/BlE2u0

Answer (score 0):

Utilize `pd.pivot_table` com 'nunique' no parâmetro *aggfunc*, assim você vai agrupar as datas e contar os valores distintos de 'Cod_Cli':

```py
import pandas as pd

his_corretagem_bovespa = [
    { 'Date': '10/01/2023', 'Cod_Cli': 'A' },
    { 'Date': '10/01/2023', 'Cod_Cli': 'A' },
    { 'Date': '10/01/2023', 'Cod_Cli': 'A' },
    { 'Date': '10/01/2023', 'Cod_Cli': 'A' },
    { 'Date': '10/01/2023', 'Cod_Cli': 'B' },
    { 'Date': '10/01/2023', 'Cod_Cli': 'B' },
    { 'Date': '11/01/2023', 'Cod_Cli': 'A' },
    { 'Date': '11/01/2023', 'Cod_Cli': 'B' }
]
df = pd.DataFrame(his_corretagem_bovespa)  # Transforma a lista para DataFrame do Pandas

df.pivot_table(values='Cod_Cli', index='Date', aggfunc='nunique').reset_index()  # Cria a tabela sumarizada e reseta os indexes.
```